# How to check if an array exists in List of arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I have a List of Arrays ... And I want to check if an exact array is in List or not

```
  List<int[]> Output = new List<int[]>();
```

I have an Array

```
int[] coordinates
```

I want to check if coordinates array is exactly in List or Not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `SequenceEqual`:

```
bool result = Output.Any(a => a.SequenceEqual(coordinates));
```